# Java MP3 Loop ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

So this is for a school assignment, but I've been working at it for a couple hours now and I've lost hope. The idea of the assignment was to create a main MP3 Class, then using another class Titled MP3Collection, create new MP3 objects and add them to an ArrayList, then later print them out numbered and with all data.

I've having issues trying to figure out how to loop and print the values of the ArrayList

Here is the code for MP3.java, although it's just mainly getting and setting functions.

```
    public class MP3 {

    //Initiate Variables
    private String artist;
    private String song;
    private String album;
    private int trackLength;

    //Constructor
    public MP3(String artistName, String songName, String albumName, int trackLeng){
        setArtist(artistName);
        setSong(songName);
        setAlbum(albumName);
        setLength(trackLeng);
    }

    //**** Set Functions ****

    //Set Artist
    public void setArtist(String artistName){ artist = artistName; }

    //Set Song
    public void setSong(String songName){ song = songName; }

    //Set Album
    public void setAlbum(String albumName){ album = albumName; }

    //Set Length
    public void setLength(int trackLeng){ trackLength = trackLeng; }


    //**** Get Functions ****

    //Get Artist
    public String getArtist(){ return artist; }

    //Get Song
    public String getSong(){ return song; }

    //Get Album
    public String getAlbum(){ return album; }

    //Get Length
    public int getLength(){ return trackLength; }

    //To String
    public String toString(){

        if(getLength() <= 0) {
            setLength(60);
        }

        return String.format("%s, %s, %s, %d : %d",
            getArtist(), getSong(), getAlbum(),
            getLength() / 60, getLength() - (getLength() / 60) * 60); //Converts Seconds to Min : Sec
    } 
}
```

The second part was being able to create a class named MP3Collection and add values to the arrayList. I haven't used ArrayList much before, which I feel is why this is becoming a pain.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MP3Collection {

    //Instance Variables
    private int count = 0;
    ArrayList<Object> MP3List = new ArrayList<Object>();

    //Get Method
    public int getCount(){ return count; }

    //Set Method
    public void addMP3(String artist, String song, String album, int length) {
        MP3 newInfo = new MP3(artist, song, album, length);
    }

    public void outputInfo() {

        for (int i=0; i < MP3List.size(); i++) {            
            String sonOutput = String.format("Song[%d]: %s: %s, %s, %d", count, artist, song, album, length);
        }
    }
}
```

As it's obvious, the outputInfo function is where my trouble is. I've tried using counter as a means of grabbing the info, however, since it is an Object ArrayList, it gives me an error.

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do exactly in order to grab the correct data (song, artist, album, and length) from the ArrayList. Thank you.

Comment: Answer updated. Please ask if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Change your MP3List ArrayList from `ArrayList<Object>` to a `ArrayList<MP3>`. If you use a valid generic list here, the compiler will help make sure *at compile time* that you only add MP3 objects to the list. This is one of the main reasons to use generics.
2. Rename MP3List to mp3List to comply with Java naming standards -- all variables and method names should start with a lower-case letter.
3. Fix your `addMP3` method. Your current code creates a MP3 object, but does nothing with it.  Instead, in the method add the created MP3 to the mp3List ArrayList.
4. In the `outputInfo` method actually output the data in the ArrayList. YOu don't need StringFormat here, just a simple println will suffice.
5. The `getCount()` method only has to return the size of the mp3List, that's it. Because of this, there's no need for the count int field.

Comment: I'll get right on this. I knew about the light naming standards errors, just forgot to get to them. Thank you.

Comment: Having made all these corrections, I'm still uncertain about to specifically pull each individual object. The next part of the assignment is to "add 5 MP3s to the collection. The program outputs the number of MP3s in the collection and the information about all MP3s in the collection." That being said, trying to grab from the new ArrayList presents me with "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<MP3>"

Comment: @LoganV: the error suggests that you're trying to use array indices, e.g., `myArray[i]` to get stuff from the ArrayList, and that won't work. You need to use the ArrayList's `get(i)` to get the i'th item from the list. Have you gone through an ArrayList tutorial? You should because it looks like you're doing an awful lot of guessing here.